# Curl command with delete option throws an exception

Tags: powershell, curl, elasticsearch

I have been working on Elastic search for a while and I have scenario to delete some indices in the elasticsearch.

As instructed in the ELK user guide, am trying to delete the indices using the `CURL` command in PowerShell on Windows Server 2012 R2

The command is given below

```
curl -X DELETE 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016.12.19/'
```

But when I give this command to delete in PowerShell, it throws the below error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'X'.
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -X DELETE 'http://10.242.244.170:9200/logstash-2016.12.19/'
+      ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Curl` is an alias for the [`Invoke-WebRequest`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217035) cmdlet. It has no `-X` parameter but a `-Method`:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Delete -Uri 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016.12.19/'
```